# How to import an exported constant from typescript file to javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to import a constant from typescript file in javascript file but I'm always ending up with `Unexpected token, expected ,` error.

Here is the constant in ts file:

```
export const articleQuery = (slug: string, categorySlug?: string) => 'context'
```

And I want to be able to use this function in a javascript file like this and pass the params.

```js
import {articleQuery} from "./path/to/file.ts"

const query = articleQuery(slug, categorySlug)
```

I'm not sure if this is doable or not, but any recommendations to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) compile ts file with `tsc path/to/file.ts` into `path/to/file.js` and use that (general usage)

b) if you are running with `tsx`, `ts-node` or typescript `--loader`, just import `./path/to/file` or `./path/to/file.js`, that should work

c) why do you ever need to import ts from js? write a comment if you need further explanation

Comment: I have a ts file that includes a lot of queries in the format that is shown in the question. I want to test those queries during CI/CD on bitbucket pipelines using [k6](https://k6.io/). bottom line, the reason is that I want to test those queries in a js file that's why I need to import them.

Comment: I'm using https://tsdx.io/ .. would appreciate more explanation to your answer. an example would be great

Comment: see https://github.com/grafana/k6-template-typescript

Comment: What if I want to keep my test file to js, can you help with an example for you answer on how can I import a constant from ts in a js file?

Comment: You can't import any TS from pure JS. You either need `node --loader typescript` or `ts-node` equivalents.

Comment: Why do you don't want TS there?

Comment: Because I'm already using tsdx.io which doesn't generate js file in dist folder for each file. therefore I can't run the k6 test.

Comment: Well, that's absolutely not the question you've asked, and I dunno

Comment: You answered the question when you told me that we can't import TS from pure JS :) Thanks